# Interpreting minidump files from Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, bsod, dump

I have a couple of minidump files generated by blue screen crashes on a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 machine. I have installed the debugging tools and I am able to look at the contents of these files. However, I don't know how to find out the device driver and stop code that caused the crash. Can anyone provide some guidance on where this information is on the output that dumpchk.exe generates from the minidump files?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time I have a minidump to analyze, I go back to this article on NetworkWorld because it is clear, concise, and gets me through it pretty quickly:

http://www.networkworld.com/news/2005/041105-windows-crash.html?page=1

Answer (score 2):

This [MS support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263) may be of assistance.